# Using try except to find if a key exist in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, try-catch

I was wondering the best way to find if a key exist in python dictionary, not visiting the whole list of keys again and again. I am thinking of try except. Is there any better way?

Comment: You'll need to give a bit more context. The way to find if a key is in a dictionary is `key in dict`, so it's not at all clear what you're referring to with try and except and visiting lists.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on "not visiting the whole list of keys again and again", please show the code. Otherwise, you can use `my_dict.get(key)` which returns `None` if the key doesn't exist

Comment: checking if a key is in a dictionary is constant time O(1)

Comment: If you're considering try catch to assign a default value, just use what @roganjosh recommended and use the default keyword arg: `x = foo_dict.get(key, default='some default')`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `in` operator:

```
print('some_key' in my_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way would be be to follow the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) (Easier to Ask for Forgivenes than Permission) principle.

That means assuming the key is in the dict, and catching the exception if it's not, like so:

```
my_dict = {"key": "value"}
try:
    print my_dict["badkey"]
except KeyError:
    print "No such key found"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mureinik mentioned, you can just use:

```
key_name in dict
```

to return either true or false. However, if you desperately wanted to use try and except, you could use:

```
try:
    x = dict[key_name]
except KeyError:
    # Handle error here
```